# Why does India have more than 1 MCC (Mobile Country Code)?

Tags: telecommunication, wireless-communication

I was checking the [list of MCC (Mobile Country Codes) on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code#India_-_IN) and found that India has two MCC: 404 and 405. 404 contains only GSM/UMTS/LTE operator bands and 405 contains both GSM/UMTS/LTE and CDMA operator bands. The problem is that I do not understand the reason for having 2 MCC for the same country. We also have mobile network code (MNC) to differentiate between various operators, circles and the bands.

Comment: This question may be related to technology, but it doesn't address any engineering concerns.

Comment: @Fred maybe the question is not strictly about engineering, but a bit of Google-fu soon found a plausible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mobile Network Code (MNC) is either a two digit ("European" standard) or three digit ("North American" standard) identifier, with in the Mobile Country Code (MCC).

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_mobile_subscriber_identity, the 3GPP specification 23.003 recommends that the "length of the MNC is uniform within a given MCC area".

Looking at the OP's link, presumably India was allocated MCC = 404 and started using two-digit MNC numbers, but then came close to running out of numbers. The additional MCC = 405 has blocks of three-digit numbers as well as two-digit, so they may be unlikely to ever need another MCC allocation.

Comment: @Fred looks like you got beaten to the post....

Answer (score 0):

Two codes to provide sufficient bandwidth springs to mind.

Comment: As it stands this answer is more of a comment. More detail would improve this answer.

Comment: @Fred go ahead then.